# Extracting time from Java string with other characters

Tags: java, string, formatting

I'm quite new to Java and I have a `String` in this format:

```
String time = "2016-06-25T14:21:10+08:00";
```

I would like to extract the time within the `String` and output it in `HH:mm` format.

```
14:21
```

How can I do so? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-):

```
time.substring(11, 16)
```

This will extract from the `11` character (which is the start of `14:21`) to `16` character (exclusive, which is just outside the `14:21`).

Answer (score 1):

[`DateTimeFormatter`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) can be used for this purpose:

```
String input = "2016-06-25T14:21:10+08:00";

DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");

TemporalAccessor time = parseFormatter.parse(input);
String output = formatter.format(time);
```